# fancontrol for GPU FAN is not working - Failed to start fan speed regulator

Tags: fan, fancontrol

fancontrol for GPU FAN GP108 Geforce GT1030 is not working - Failed to start fan speed regulator.

Failed to start

```
● fancontrol.service - fan speed regulator
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-01-17 22:27:45 EET; 3min 56s ago
       Docs: man:fancontrol(8)
             man:pwmconfig(8)
    Process: 17456 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/fancontrol --check (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 17 22:27:45 eliasc systemd[1]: Starting fan speed regulator...
Jan 17 22:27:45 eliasc fancontrol[17456]: Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Jan 17 22:27:45 eliasc fancontrol[17456]: Some mandatory settings missing, please check your config file!
Jan 17 22:27:45 eliasc systemd[1]: fancontrol.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 17 22:27:45 eliasc systemd[1]: fancontrol.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 17 22:27:45 eliasc systemd[1]: Failed to start fan speed regulator.
```

fancontrol config

```
# Configuration file generated by pwmconfig, changes will be lost
INTERVAL=10

DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0 hwmon1=devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 hwmon3=devices/platform/it87.2608
DEVNAME=hwmon0=acpitz hwmon1=nouveau hwmon3=it8620

FCTEMPS=hwmon1/GPU_temp=/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input
FCFANS =hwmon1/GPU_fan= /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/hwmon/hwmon1/fan1_input

MINTEMP=hwmon1/GPU_temp=20 
MAXTEMP=hwmon1/GPU_temp=90 

MINSTART=hwmon1/GPU_fan=400 
MINSTOP =hwmon1/GPU_fan=0 

MAXPWM  =hwmon1/GPU_fan=220
```

GPU card (as PCI) - (GForce) with nouveau drivers

```
elias@eliasc:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/hwmon/hwmon1$ vdir
σύνολο 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan 17 20:44 device -> ../../../0000:01:00.0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:44 fan1_input
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:44 name
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jan 17 20:42 power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 21:51 pwm1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 21:53 pwm1_enable
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 22:12 pwm1_max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 22:12 pwm1_min
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan 17 20:42 subsystem -> ../../../../../../class/hwmon
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 22:12 temp1_auto_point1_pwm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 22:12 temp1_auto_point1_temp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 22:12 temp1_auto_point1_temp_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:44 temp1_crit
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:44 temp1_crit_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:44 temp1_emergency
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:44 temp1_emergency_hyst
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:44 temp1_input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:44 temp1_max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:44 temp1_max_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 20:42 uevent
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan 17 22:12 update_interval
```

GPU controller is set to 0

```
cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm1_enable
    0
```

info - How can I change that value?

```
hwmon device attribute pwm1_enable:
0: PWM offline (fan is set to full-speed mode)
1: Manual PWM control (use pwm1 to set fan level)
2: Hardware PWM control (EC "auto" mode)
3: reserved (Software PWM control, not implemented yet)
```

Not valid parameter --->

```
echo 1 | sudo tee pwm1_enable
```

Is there any option to set manually gpu fan speed using terminal command?

Comment: Did you add `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to your grub config and rebuild it?

Comment: No, but I think ACPI is enabled. How i can check that?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

My GPU fan speed was 800 - 900rpm and did a lot of noise. Therefore, I wanted to control it.

Note that I have a very powerful airpump that I used on the fan.
Also I unscrew the fan of GPU, and clean it. However, the problem was not solved.

Finally, I stuck some tape on the center of the fan, and speed fan increased 1100-1300rpm!!!! Dont know why. Probably, fan geometry changed ?